# R: How can I calculate the F-statistic of a logistic model in R?

Tags: r, logistic, statistical-significance, goodness-of-fit

I am running a logistic regression in R and I noticed that the output does not include the F-statistic which shows the overall significance of the model.

In another [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/148204/how-is-the-f-stat-in-a-regression-in-r-calculated), the formula for the F-statistic is given for a linear regression. My question is, is the F-statistic a valid measure of significance for the logistic model? if so, how can I calculate it?

Comment: You would be better served with a chi-squared test or an ROC curve. There is also a R^2 for Logistic regression

Comment: Run the first example on the help page for `glm` to see what can be done.  Notice that the usual summary gives you a null and residual deviance: those are what you use instead of the F statistic.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=analysis+of+deviance+score%3A2.

Comment: First, you may want to use `car:: Anova` with the wald test, to look at individual effects. If you want to test the model overall, perhaps fit a model *result ~ 1* and use *lmtest* to compare that to your full model.

Comment: So, to be clear, neither of the things I'm suggesting are an F statistic.  But the chi-square statistics may serve better.

Answer (score 1):

## TSS

```
TSS <- function(y){
  y_ = mean(y)
  y = y - y_
  y = y^2
  sum(y)
}
```

## RSS

```
RSS <- function(error){
  sum(error^2)
}
```

## F-statistics

```
FS <- function(tss, rss, num_of_predictors, num_of_sample){
  a=(tss-rss)/num_of_predictors
  b = rss/(num_of_sample-num_of_predictors-1)
  a/b
}

num_of_predictors = length(cars)-1
num_of_sample = length(y)
error = fit$residuals
```